How can I automatically annotate PGN games with ECO codes and opening names?
I have my chess repertoire in PGN format. It's composed of small separate games for each different variation, containing only the opening phase of each game. I want to insert the name of the opening as an annotation in each game.
For example:

d4 g6 2. e4 Bg7 3. Nc3 {B06: Modern Defense with 3.Nc3} 3...b6 4. f4 Bb7 5. Nf3 *

